# Test if value in a Pandas series is in an array

Tags: python, pandas

This seems like the answer will be something obvious but...

I have a series like this:

```
Dataset['Variable'] = ['a','b','b','a','e','c','d']
```

and a list like this:

```
List_vals1 = ['a','b']
List_vals2 = ['e','c','d']
```

I want to create 2 new variables in the dataset to see if the value of Dataset['Variable'] is in each list.

```
Dataset['Var_for_List_vals1'] = ['1','1','1','1','0','0','0']
Dataset['Var_for_List_vals2'] = ['0','0','0','0','1','1','1']
```

I tried to do this:

```
Dataset['Var_for_List_vals1'] = (Dataset[Dataset['Variable' in List_vals1]])*1 (times 1 to convert to numeric)
```

and python did not like that solution.

This seems like an obvious one but nothing seems to work for me.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that using `map` will become much slower than the `numpy.in1d` method, when data dimension gets large:

```
In [1]:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
In [7]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'Variable': ['a','b','b','a','e','c','d']*100}) #700 lines of data
List_vals1 = ['a','b']
List_vals2 = ['e','c','d']
In [8]:

df['var_for_List_vals1'] = np.in1d(df.Variable, List_vals1)
#return Boolean values
In [9]:

%timeit np.in1d(df.Variable, List_vals1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 112 µs per loop
In [10]:

%timeit map(lambda x: 1 if x in List_vals1 else 0, df['Variable'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 287 µs per loop
```

See doc [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and `lambda` can achieve what you need:

```
# I believe you want 1, 0 not '1', '0'.
Dataset['var_for_List_vals1'] = map(lambda x: 1 if x in List_vals1 else 0, Dataset['Variable'])
Dataset['var_for_List_vals1']
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

Dataset['var_for_List_vals2'] = map(lambda x: 1 if x in List_vals2 else 0, Dataset['Variable'])   
Dataset['var_for_List_vals2']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

If you do want '1' and '0' feel free to change `...(lambda x: '1' ... else '0')`